A question about manifold embedding
If $M^{m}$ is a compact manifold that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$, how to prove $M^{m} \times S^{n}$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}?$
I came across this exercise when I was studying manifolds. What I don't understand is that $S^n$ can't be embedded in $R^n$, so why $M^{m} \times S^{n}$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}?$ What is its mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}?$
Thanks your help!

What have you tried?

@DietrichBurde I constructed the charts of M^m \times S^n, but I don't know how to embedded in R^m+n+1.

If $M^m$ is embedded in $R^{m+1}$, its normal bundle must be trivial (equivalently $M$ is orientable). Then its normal bundle is also trivial in $R^{n+1+m}$ and has a tubular neigbourhood diffeomorphic to $M\times R^{n+1}$, and the result follows.

The parenthetical "equivalently" remark confuses me.

@Thorgott A trivialization of the normal bundle, say by a normal vector field $V$ along $M$, defines an orientation of $M$ : decide that a basis of $T_p(M)$ is positive is $(B,V(p))$ is a positive basis of $R^n$. Conversely if $M$ is orientable you can construct $V$ as the unique orthogonal vector field along $M$ such that  $(B,V(p))$ is positive.
